# CustomAction Types in AEM From Component

Tags: aem

I am creating a form using form-components. I have email-field and UserName field. I want to send an email to the given email id on click of submit button. In the form I select my custom action type which invoke a servlet which is responsible to send an email. My custom action type has only forward.jsp as script file :

```
<%@page import="com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FormsConstants"%><sling:defineObjects/><%
      System.out.println(":::::::::::::::"+resource.getPath());  
    FormsHelper.setForwardPath(slingRequest, resource.getPath() + ".custommail.html");
    FormsHelper.setRedirectToReferrer(request, true);
%>
```

I can see my forward.jsp is getting called when i click submit button, as i can see resourcePath(content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/newsletter/jcr:content/par/start) in stdout.log. But servlet not getting call, In case i hit   `localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/newsletter/jcr:content/par/start.custommail.html` servlet gets invoke, don't know why its not invoking with FormsHelper.

And also how can we pass parameter i.e. email-field to servlet.

Any Idea.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a servlet registered to your form start component and the proper selector. If you are using the foundation form this would be something like this:

```
@SlingServlet(resoruceTypes = "foundation/components/form/start", methods = "POST", selectors = "custommail", extenstions = "html", generateComponent = false)
public class CustomMailServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(final SlingHttpServletRequest request, final SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this blog http://labs.sixdimensions.com/blog/2012-08-20/sending-email-adobe-cq-api/ to get and understanding of Email functionality in AEM.

Comment: Thanks, Issue till now is not with email functionality. Problem is my servlet not getting call with custom action type.